# Split multiple entries on basis of separator

Tags: r, split

I've got a vector that looks something like this:

```
df <- c("201/304", "445.5/553", "665/543/224", "332.0/433.0")
```

Multiple values have been entered into a cell with a hash separator. Some have two and some have three values (and some may have more). I'm looking for a general way to split this up to create vector with a single value in each (and no hashes).

I need something that will look like this:

```
df <- c(201, 304, 445.5, 553, 665, 543, 224, 332.0, 433)
```

I've tried `strsplit()` but then get stuck how to rearrange the output as I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df, '[/]')))
```

---

Or use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(df, '[^/]+')))
```

Comment: Did the output have to be numeric?

Comment: @polka Based on the expected output, I didn't find any quotes

Comment: thanks @akrun. What's the value of the square brackets round the slash?

Comment: @jeremylindsell - `strsplit(df, "/", fixed = TRUE)` would be the non-regex way of splitting it.  Also, `fixed = TRUE` is usually faster than using a regex.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see `scan` mentioned here yet, but the following should also work:

```
scan(text = df, sep = "/")
# Read 9 items
# [1] 201.0 304.0 445.5 553.0 665.0 543.0 224.0 332.0 433.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.

`unlist(strsplit(df, split = "/"))`

Comment: This gives the wrong class of output.  Desired output is numeric.